# How to group a tree/list view inside a fom view in Odoo 8?

Tags: xml, odoo-8, odoo

I have a tree view inside a form view and want to group it by a specific category (in this case `material`), just like in a normal tree view. Is that possible?
I tried to insert a filter before and inside the `<tree>` but that did not work:

```xml
<filter name="material" string="Nach Material" context="{'group_by': 'material'}" />
```

I found a [similar question](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/help-1/question/how-to-display-search-view-inside-a-form-63512) on the odoo forum but there seems to be no answer, except a workaround from 'Prakash' that I don't understand. A workaround would also be fine for me.

Answer (score 6):

The best thing you can do, using the Odoo framework, is to **create a button**.  You can **open a wizard showing the tree view** with that button. Like this, you can use a search view in the wizard and you can group by the elements with a normal filter.

If you still want to group the elements directly in the form I'm afraid you should create a widget in JavaScript. The widget should be easier and better, this widget should override or extend the widget that Odoo is using for that kind of fields.

I didn't make a good research but it seems that [was possible to group the list view in the forms of the 6.1 version](http://www.zbeanztech.com/blog/filtering-one2many-fields-openerp). Maybe you can make a migration of that behaviour

Anyway I recommend you to adapt you needs to the Odoo framework as much as possible to make your life easier.

But, if you finally decide to create the widget and share it with the community, would be awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work:

```xml
<field name="line_ids" context="{'group_by': 'material'}">
    <tree> ...</tree>
<field>
```